# RxJS: How to toggle to switch between multiple behavior subject sources

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

**Scenario:**

I have a grid in which I want to display data. I have potentially two (or more) behavior subject data sources. I also have a toggle observable that returns a number indicating which source I want to display data from (i.e. 1 means source 1, 2 means source 2, etc).

**Question:**

How do I combine n number of sources but only emit records from the source as indicated by the toggle observable? My grid will be subscribed to the resulting observable. When the toggle observable emits, I would expect the latest from the selected source to be emitted.

```
// Sources
let source1 = new BehaviorSubject([]);
let source2 = new BehaviorSubject([]);

// Toggle observable
let toggle = new BehaviorSubject(1); // default to source one

// Combined observable
let gridDataSource = ????
```

Comment: If you don't need to emit an initial value then try `com­bineLat­est` or   `with­Lat­est­From`. If the order is important then use `concatMap` and if its not then use `mergeMap`, `switchMap` or `flatMap`

Comment: I do need an initial value, but I'm not sure what you mean by order. I only want to emit from one of the sources depending on which one is selected. Essentially, the grid will have a source drop down selector beside it.

Comment: Instead of creating many  b.subjects, can't you create a single one and then later you can subscribe to it. Because all sub­scribers to a sub­ject share the same exe­cu­tion of the sub­ject. On your dropdown selector, you can add values via `.next()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `switchMap` can do the trick here. It is by definition its purpose to switch between multiple sources.

```
// Sources
let sources = [
  new BehaviorSubject([]),
  new BehaviorSubject([]),
];

// Toggle observable
let toggle = new BehaviorSubject(0); // default to the first source

// Selected observable
let gridDataSource = toggle.switchMap((i) => source[i]);
```

If you cannot, or don't want to use an array of sources, you can fallback to a simple switch-case inside the switchMap declaration.

```
let gridDataSource = toggle.switchMap((i) => {
    switch(i) {
        case 1: return source1;
        case 2: return source2;
    }
});
```

Comment: Was able to implement this very quickly without issue and it behaves exactly as I was hoping. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Noémi Salaün's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49039637/4632627) is great, it set me in the right direction, but you can make it a little more dynamic with even less code, also the RxJs syntax is a little outdated, so I've added an updated/improved version here too.

```js
// as many as you like, in an array, map, or any other structure you like
source_a = new Subject();
source_b = new Subject();

// just directly pass them to the BehaviourSubject, no need for the array/index
toggle_source = new BehaviorSubject(source_a);
source = toggle_source.pipe(switchMap(source => source));

// change a source
toggle_source.next(source_b)
```